# Buzzer circuit understanding

Tags: microcontroller, power, dc-motor, piezo-buzzer

I have a question concerning this circuit I have found on internet since I would like to replace it with a mini dc motor vibrator.

Is there any chance someone could explain to me how it works?

As far as I can see. You have an input of 5.9V to operate and PWN 4KHz from the output of a MCU.

How does can you control the intensity of the vibrator using this circuit? I would replace the buzzer, PKLC1212E4001-R1 with a dc motor, does that seem okay?

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the circuit (everything above the 4k7 resistor) is just a power supply to create the high voltage (+24 VDC) required for the buzzer. The transistor functions as a low-side switch for the buzzer itself.

There isn't much about this circuit that would be in common with a motor driver, which would require more current and less voltage.